# If $a \notin A \setminus B$ and $a \in A$ , show that $a \in B $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $a \notin A \setminus B$ and $a \in A$ , show that $a \in B $.

hi. i am studying the basic set theory.

I want to prove that statement. but precisely i don't know the proof.

Comment: $A\setminus B$={$a\in A | a \notin B$}. What means $a \notin A\setminus B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) and the identity $A \setminus B = A \cap B^\complement$, we have
$$\begin{align} a \notin A \setminus B &\iff a \in (A \setminus B)^\complement \\&\iff a \in (A \cap B^\complement)^\complement \\&\iff a \in A^\complement \cup B \end{align}$$

So at least one of $a \in A^\complement$ or $a \in B$ must be true.  But $a \in A \implies a \notin A^\complement$, so we must have $a \in B.$

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that $A = (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B)$. [If you haven't proved that, or perhaps defined $A \setminus B$ through this relation, then you should do that).

But given that, you have that any $a$ is either in $A \setminus B$, or $a \in A \cap B$. Since your prescribed $a$ is not in $A \setminus B$, we have that $a \in A \cap B$, and thus $a \in A$ and $a \in B$.

Answer (score 0):

$A - B = \{a  : a \in A \land a\notin B\}$.

Let's say $a \in A$. Then $a \notin A - B$ implies directly:

$a$ is s.t $\neg(a \in A \land a \notin B)$. Which is equivalent to saying $(a \notin A \lor a \in B)$. Since we have $a \in A$ you get $a \in B$..